# spring data mongodb maximum likes

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I am using mongodb having a collection,in which i am storing status of a item for a different users,it is like `"userItemstatus" = 1 or 2`.which means 1 for liking the item and 2 for disliking the item.

```
"_id" : NumberLong(104009),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.registration.UserItemHistory",
    "user_id" : NumberLong(85861),
    "item_id" : NumberLong(103468),
    "catagory" : "MISCELLANEOUS",
    "userItemStatus" : 1,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:43:40.351Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:43:43.780Z")
}
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(104018),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.registration.UserItemHistory",
    "user_id" : NumberLong(85861),
    "item_id" : NumberLong(103352),
    "catagory" : "MISCELLANEOUS",
    "userItemStatus" : 2,
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-02-08T11:44:26.803Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2016-03-17T19:34:07Z")
}
```

Now i want get the item which got most liked. i,e item which have  most number of `"userItemStatus"= 1`. I have read about aggregation but i am having problem of using it with spring data mongodb. I am new in using spring data mongodb. Please help.

Comment: simutaneously u have to update the item  based on category in item collection  {categorycount :{
    "MISCELLANEOUS" : 3,
    "MISCELLANEOUS1" : 1,
    "MISCELLANEOUS2" : 4
}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ValueCount {

    private String userid;
    private int likes;
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }


}
public List<ValueCount> agg(){
    Criteria cr = Criteria.where("userItemStatus").is("1");

    MatchOperation m = match(cr);
    GroupOperation g = group("item_id").count().as("count");
    ProjectionOperation p = project("count").and("item_id").previousOperation();
    SortOperation s = sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"count");
    LimitOperation limit = limit(20);
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(m,g,p,s,limit);
    AggregationResults<ValueCount> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,"user_likedislike",ValueCount.class);
    return groupResults.getMappedResults();
}
```

You will anyway get sorted results starting from highest likes.You can limit elements using `LimitOperation limit = limit(20);`Replace `user_likedislike` with your collection name

Comment: thanx for the answer ,but its givng me null when  i am priting groupResults.getMappedResults().

Comment: i have edited post with some change.it will work now i didn't test that but it will.make sure your collection name in place of `user_likedislike`